# How to define coordinate system in pymol?

Tags: pymol

I want to know the position vector of some atoms in pymol. I can calculate the distances but I need the position vector instead. How can I get the atomic coordinate with respect to some define system of coordinate?

Suppose there are two atoms. How can I get the coordinates (x,y,z) of those two atoms? There must be a reference frame to calculate these coordinates with respect to it. What is that reference frame in pymol?

Comment: What file format? Since a `pdb` file largely consists of coordinates, either you are using a different file type or I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am completely new to pymol. The file format is `pdb`. How can I get those coordinates? Where is the origin?

Comment: I haven't done much with pymol beyond using it a few times to generate cool pictures, but I did a project for a course last spring to generate protein contact maps from pdb files and found it fairly easy to write a Python function to extract the data I needed from the files. See this for a description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank_(file_format) . On the other hand, I would be surprised if pymol didn't have some built-in parsing tools, so I would explore the help a bit more before parsing it yourself.

Comment: If I have time I'll try to write up something tomorrow about how I extracted the data with Python. The coordinates are in angstroms and (I think) are relative to the centroid of the molecule. When I was doing this last spring I found the following quite helpful: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/101/static101.do?p=education_discussion/Looking-at-Structures/coordinates.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Python function to extract data from a `pdb` file. It returns a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries. The outer dictionary is keyed by the model number and the inner dictionaries are keyed by the atom number in the model and then, each line is read into a dictionary keyed by the fields of interest in the corresponding atom record:

```
def parsePDB(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()

    modelNum = 1
    multiModel = False
    d = {1:{}}
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split()
        record = fields[0] if len(fields)> 0 else ''
        if record == "MODEL":
            if multiModel:
                modelNum += 1
                d[modelNum] = {}
            else:
                multiModel = True
        elif record == "ATOM":
            num = int(fields[1])
            atomDict = {}
            atomDict["atom"] = fields[2]
            atomDict["amino"] = fields[3]
            atomDict["chain"] = fields[4]
            atomDict["residue"] = int(fields[5])
            atomDict["xyz"] = (float(fields[6]),float(fields[7]),float(fields[8]))
            d[modelNum][num] = atomDict
    return d
```

Some testing code:

```
d = parsePDB("2HIU.pdb")
atom = d[3][358]
print("atom",358,"of model",3,"is the",atom["atom"], "atom of a", atom["amino"],"amino acid")
print("It is located on residue", atom["residue"], "of chain",atom["chain"])
print("Its coordinates are", atom["xyz"])
```

Output:

```
atom 358 of model 3 is the OD1 atom of a ASN amino acid
It is located on residue 3 of chain B
Its coordinates are (13.093, 5.012, -5.549)
```

This is from the file [2HIU.pdb](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=2HIU). The line from the file used in the test code looks like:

```
ATOM    358  OD1 ASN B   3       6.882   2.397  -4.401  1.00  0.00           O
```

Here is what the corresponding innermost dictionary looks like:

```
>>> d[3][358]
{'atom': 'OD1', 'chain': 'B', 'amino': 'ASN', 'residue': 3, 'xyz': (13.093, 5.012, -5.549)}
```

There are two complications to keep in mind:

1) Not all these files have multiple models. In fact, most do not and lack lines which begin `MODEL`. If `len(d)` is 1 then there is only a single model in the file.

2) The `HETATM` records correspond to atoms that are not part of the protein per se but are somehow bound up with it. I ignored those completely. Your purposes might require that you use them -- in which case you would need to tweak the code.